# Noncyclic vectors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am supposed to show that if we have a $3\times 3$ matrix with $3$ distinct eigenvalues then the non-cyclic vectors are a union of $3$ distinct, $2$-dimensional subspaces. I am not really sure how to tackle this problem.

*My try:*

Let $A$ be the matrix in question. Then $A=PBP^{-1}$ where $B$ is the diagonal matrix with the distinct eigenvectors. My first instinct was to check if $B$ has any noncyclic vectors, $v,Bv,B^2v$ gives this matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & a & a^2 \\
    1 & b & b^2 \\
    1 & c & c^2  
\end{bmatrix}
where $a,b,c$ are distinct eigenvalues, this matrix is invertible so all vectors (where no entry is $0$) are cyclic. Thus only vectors with some entry $0$ are non cyclic. clearly all such vectors are non-cyclic. Thus I found my $3$ distinct subspaces whose union gives the non cyclic vectors. However, my problem is justifying why noncyclic vectors of $B$ correspond to noncyclic vectors of $A$. Afterall, $A$ might not be diagonal only similar to $B$

Comment: That's basically it: the reduction to diagonal $B$ is perfectly valid. Another way to look at it is that you have a basis of eigenvectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ and the cyclic vectors are the $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_3v_3$ with all the $a_i$ non-zero.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I see, so the method here, shows that there exist such subspaces. I show they exist in respect to one basis, but then it also exists in respect to the standard basis.